# Using more than 2 IF conditions to identify different data types in a mixed column - Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, nested-if

I am trying to Add a new Column that uses multiple If conditions to check if a particular column contains a specific text, numbers formatted as text or textual values.

The below If conditon works only for the first 2 criteria but adding a 3rd checking criteria does not yield the desired NULL results for numeric values that are formatted as text.

```
===============================
ColumnToCheck       | NewColumn
===============================
R0                  |  Questions
Is this my life?    |  Is this my life?
0.5445              |  null
0.23                |  null
0.23335             |  null
===============================
```

The formula is:

```
= Table.AddColumn(PreviousStep, "NewColumn", 
    each    
if 
       Value.Is([ColumnToCheck],Text.Type) and not Text.Contains([ColumnToCheck],"R0") then 
     [ColumnToCheck] 
else if 
  Text.Contains([ColumnToCheck],"R0", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then 
     "Questions" 
else if 
Value.Is(Number.FromText([ColumnToCheck]),type number) then 
     null 
else 
     null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like that

```
 if
    try Value.Is(Number.FromText([ColumnToCheck]), type number) otherwise Value.Is([ColumnToCheck],type number)  
then 
    null 
else 
    if 
       Value.Is([ColumnToCheck],Text.Type) and not Text.Contains([ColumnToCheck],"R0") 
    then 
        [ColumnToCheck] 
    else 
        if 
            Value.Is([ColumnToCheck],Text.Type) and  Text.Contains([ColumnToCheck],"R0", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
        then 
            "Questions" 
        else 
            null
```

Result in PQ looks like

[image]